# Filled cell number under a Specific row name

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to get the total number of filled cells in an excel table that are in a row with a specific name

I have a table that that multiple rows with the same name, i would like to calculate the filled cells under a specific name.

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUZxV.png)
I would like to calculate the total number of filled cells that are in Rows with the name Full Day Course. and then do the same with the rows names Half day course

I have tried sum and count functions but they gave me errors